# The memory usage reported in cgroup differs from the free command

Tags: linux, memory-usage, cgroup

Why would the free command be reporting a much different mem usage number vs cgroup?

```
$ free -b 
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:     2096914432   520863744  1112170496    35389440   463880192  1356828672
Swap:    2145382400           0  2145382400

$ cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.usage_in_bytes 
857239552
```

The documentation for cgroups says that memory.usage_in_bytes is a "fuzz value". I'm guessing that just means it reports an estimate that's close to the actual value. Even if it's an estimate, I don't think it should be this far off.

I'm running Linux Mint 18.2 in a VirutalBox VM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`memory.usage_in_bytes` and `memory.max_usage_in_bytes` report RSS+CACHE, so in terms of your `free` output:

```
memory.usage_in_bytes ~= free.used + free.(buff/cache) - (buff)
```

You may also be interested in `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.stat`, though I still couldn't find/compute the `free.used` value from the `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.stat` output.

Comment: What's the difference between `free.(buff/cache)` and `(buff)` in this answer? It's not clear where you're getting the `(buff)` value from. `free.used` and `free.(buff/cache)` are clearly from the output of running `free`.

Comment: @davidparks21 as far as I recall, the thing is that you cannot find pure `(buff)`, but `memory.usage_in_bytes` seems to only include the cache